# How can I convert raw binary data to a blob and display it in an img tag?

Tags: javascript, image, electron, blob, svelte

I'm making a dream journal application in Electron and Svelte.  I have a custom file format containing a title, description, and one or more images.  See:

### Program Input

[image: program input]

### File Output

[image: file output]

When I need to, I can call `ipcRenderer.invoke()` to read the file in the main process, then return that to retrieve it in the renderer process (don't worry, I'm using `async` `await` to make sure I'm not just getting a promise.  **Also, for my testing, I'm only sending back the Uint8Array representative of the image**).

After attempting to display the image and failing, I decided I'd check to see that I was receiving the information as intended.  I sent the response as-is back to the main process and wrote it to a file.  When I opened the file in Paint, it displayed.

So, the information is correct.  This is the code I tried to display the image with:

### within `<script>`

```js
let src;
onMount(async () => {
  let a = await ipcRenderer.invoke("file-read");
  console.log(a);
  let blob = new Blob(a, {type: 'image/png'});
  console.log(blob);
  ipcRenderer.send("verify-content", a); // this is the test I mentioned, where it was written to a file
  src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
});
```

### in the body

```html
{#if src}
  <img src={src} />
{/if}
```

I also tried it another way:

### within `<script>`

```js
onMount(async () => {
  let a = await ipcRenderer.invoke("file-read");
  console.log(a);
  let blob = new Blob(a, {type: 'image/png'});
  console.log(blob);
  ipcRenderer.send("verify-content", a);
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  img.onload = function() {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
  }
  document.getElementById("target").appendChild(img);
});
```

### in the body

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

### However, this is all I got:

[image: I only get that little image icon]

It does not display.  How can I display this image?  All the other "blob to img" examples I found used the `type="file"` `<input />` tag.  If possible, I'd like to avoid using a Base64 data URI.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I have to wrap my Uint8Array in an array when I make a blob out of it (wtf).

```js
let blob = new Blob([a], {type: "image/png"});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!